# Append dict results in Python from multiple API calls in for loop

Tags: python

So, I am using an API to extract hierarchical data. I want to iterate through the results of one get request and use each result in a new api get request.

The second request will occur for each item in the original results. The next step is to append these new results as new rows in a data frame. So, something like this…

```
response = requests.get(some api)

data = []
for I in response:
    New_resp = requests.get(some api)
    D = New_resp["results"]
    D.append(data)

Df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The second api request returns a dict type. I cannot seem to get the append to work correctly in the loop. I only ever get the final call of the second api request, at best… sorry for the format of my post, early morning posting from my phone.

Comment: You probably mean: `data.append(D)`

Comment: Could you please give the dictionary which you get?

Comment: First, I see you are trying to add to D "data", which is always empty (I don't see it being filled in anyplace). You also don't seem to be doing anything with the first response (unless you only care about the number of whatever the response is, or its not part of the supplied code).  I suspect your append issue is just reversed as schwobaseggl mentioned, but hard to tell without more details.

Comment: i think you are trying to do `data.append(D)` instead of `D.append(data)`

Comment: Sorry, yes I miss-typed. Data.append(D). 

Basically, I want to created a dataframe based on each response from the api.

Comment: The response object has a type of dict. The dict consists of 4 key : value pairs, each represented in json. Each pair should be reformatted, where the key is the column and the value is the value for the row.

Comment: @user1904364 The return value from *requests.get()* is **not** subscriptable

Comment: For what it is worth, I can get the final response results to be assigned to the variable, however, I can’t seem to get each result to append instead of replace.